# Marklogic - CPU utilization is high

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

We have a cluster of 3 MarkLogic nodes. Sometimes one of its nodes runs with maximum CPU utilization. When we look in Marklogic monitoring history, we see XQDP server request rate is very high for the same period. It is around 900 requests per second. The other metrics like the request rate on the app server are not that much high.

So I think the reason for high CPU utilization may be the high XDQP request rate. if it is so, then what are possible ways through which we can reduce the number of requests on XDQP to control the CPU utilization.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

It is a little hard to answer this question without knowing more about your cluster setup and the workloads.

The XDQP Request Rate indicates that nodes are talking to other nodes within the cluster.

If one particular node has an XDQP Request Rate higher than the others, it may have data that the others need to query for (content for some common lookup doc, Security DB info, etc.). Servicing those requests will cause it to do work, which takes CPU processing power.

Look and see what other metrics correlate with that XDQP load (backups, external traffic on other appservers, scheduled tasks, reindexing activity, etc.).

If after some investigation you cannot pinpoint what is causing the load, you might consider opening a MarkLogic Support ticket to solicit their help in investigating.